# C++: member function within structures

Tags: c++, function, struct

So I have one structure that takes in an entry of four different parameters (name, artist, size, and date added), however i have another struct that is esentially a library of the entry structure and i want to create an insert memeber function within the library structure that takes one argument which is the entry to place in the library.

**in HEADER.h**

```
struct MusicEntry{
    string name, artist, date_added;
    long size;

    MusicEntry() = default;
    MusicEntry(string name_str, string artist_str, long size_int, string date_added_str) : 
    name(name_str), artist(artist_str), size(size_int), date_added(date_added_str) {};
    MusicEntry to_string();
};

struct MusicLibrary{

    MusicLibrary(string) {};
    MusicLibrary to_string();
    MusicEntry insert(); //not sure how this should be passed with MusicEntry

};
```

**in FUNCTION.cpp**

```
MusicEntry MusicLibrary::insert(){
     //some code
}
```

Each song is provided with a unique ID and that is what is essentialy being passed through the insert member function.

Comment: Are you looking for `void insert(const MusicEntry&);`? You say you want a function that takes an argument, but your code shows a function that takes none.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to write it, so I just posted what I have in my code right now.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you want MusicLibrary to contain all instances of MusicEntry, thus you should look into the generic containers such as std::vector.

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++STL.html#VECTOR

Passing the MusicEntry into the MusicLibrary should be done with either a reference (&) or a pointer (*).

```
MusicEntry* MusicLibrary::insert(const MusicEntry* myEntry){
     //some code
}
```

or

```
MusicEntry& MusicLibrary::insert(const MusicEntry& myEntry){
     //some code
}
```